# Django JWT Auth, why one request works and the other not

Tags: python, django, curl

I was trying [Django JWT Auth](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-jwt-auth) and noticed that the URL responds well to one type of post but doesn't respond well to another, but i can figure out why.

Basically, if i use the cURL POST referred in the readme.md, everything goes accordingly to planned:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"abc123"}' http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

but if you i use another type of cURL POST with the same info, it doesn't work:

```
$ curl -d 'username=admin&password=abc123' http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

I know that the "Content-Type" is diferent, but shouldn't the request be accepted in the same manner, they are both well formed posts?

Answer (score 1):

Curl's `-d` option actually sends the request like it's a web browser. My guess is that the URL you're testing against doesn't have a standard web form, so it can't actually process the request.

TL;DR Pretty sure Django JWT Auth doesn't support the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

From curl manual:

> -d --data 
>                 (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified data in a POST request to the HTTP
>                 server, in the same way that a browser  does  when  a  user  has
>                 filled  in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will
>                 cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
>                 application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F, --form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another related question. If you do a POST to Django using 'application/json'  Django POST request parser doesn't by default put on the request.POST dictionary the JSON parameters. Correct?   (it only 'magically' does this by default if you post like a browser 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but If the data you're looking for doesn't show up in request.POST, it should be in request.body. Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/

Comment: Yes it shows up in the request.body. What i meant to say is that by default Django doesn´t load the JSON parameters (Content-Type: applcation/json) to the request.POST dictionary.    As it does with typical POST where the Content-Type heading is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the body data comes in the following form 'username=some&password=some'.     Am i correct?